# two-way binding of a single object in observableArray

Tags: binding, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, two-way

My page is as follows:

```
<button id="add">Add Data</button>
<button id="show">show</button>
<table>
    <tr style="vertical-align:top">
        <td>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: students">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
                        </td>
                        <td> <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-bind="click: $root.showData">Select</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table id="data">
                <tbody data-bind="with: selectedData">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: id" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="Close" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.students = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.showData = function (dt) {
        if (window.console) console.log(dt);
        self.selectedData(dt);
        $('#data').show();
    }
    this.selectedData = ko.observable();
}
$(function () {
    window.appViewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(window.appViewModel);
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var model = window.appViewModel;
        $.each(students, function (idx, student) {
            if (window.console) console.log(student);
            model.students.push(student);
        });
        $('table').show();
    });
    $('table').hide();
    $('input').click(function () {
        $('#data').hide();
    });
    $('#show').click(function () {
        var s = JSON.stringify(window.appViewModel.students());
        alert(s);
    });
});
```

Preview:

[image]

In pic, I click on the select corresponding to student with id = 3. The other table shows up with the selected student details. Suppose I enter something in textbox 1, textbox 2 doesn't update, and vice versa.

What to do to make that happen?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/YdrQf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inputs aren't updating because the `id` and `name` values are not being stored or bound against `observables`, which are the special object that knockout provides specifically for this purpose. You can easily solve this with your code by adding a new `Student` type:

```
function Student(data) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
};
```

and use it to populate your `students` array with:

```
$.each(students, function (idx, student) {
     if (window.console) console.log(student);
     model.students.push(new Student(student));
 });
```

With those properties now being `observables`, their changes will propagate to the UI. Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdrQf/2/), with these two minor changes.

That being said, I think you have largely missed the point of Knockout. I strongly suggest you go through the [Knockout tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/), if you haven't done so already.

You're use of jQuery to create `click` functions for your viewmodel really goes against the model that Knockout encourages. Please take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZLjE/4/), which converts your code into 100% Knockout, using viewmodel functions, and drops all the jQuery.