# Binding a JSON array of objects to form fields with two-way bindings using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I am relatively new to Knockoutjs and wants to know how to achieve the functionality proposed below:

I have a array like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "records": [
      {
        "name": "a1",
        "value": "b1",
        "type": "c1"
      },
      {
        "name": "a2",
        "value": "b2",
        "type": "text"
      },
      {
        "name": "a3",
        "value": "b3",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a number of input elements mapped to the records as such:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: getValueForID(a1)" id="a1"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: getValueForID(a2)" id="a2"/>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: getValueForID(a3)" id="a3"/>
```

Can some one suggest how can I create the JSON as expected if the input elements exists but the data is empty at the start.
Meaning that incoming data was:

```
{
  "data": {
    "records": []
  }
}
```

But the user enters values for a1 and a3 input so the JSON I want to create will be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "records": [
      {
        "name": "a1",
        "value": "b1",
        "type": "c1"
      },
      {
        "name": "a3",
        "value": "b3",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Can anyone please point how do I achieve this?

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868717/two-way-binding-of-a-single-object-in-observablearray)

Comment: Best way is to use observables directly and repeating bindings (e.g. foreach). If records "don't exist", but should, create them in the model first: feeding JavaScript objects to the mapping plugin makes this easy. It's just easier. It's "okay" (but more complex) to use a function that deal with the appropriate observables - so I'd recommend this only as a fallback.

Comment: But the issue lies in the generic fashion of the data. That is the records are same while changing parameter is name that binds. Can you please show a sample for the given example?

Comment: @SangramMohite I would create all 3 "records" immediately. Then, when exporting, I would remove the "records without values". This is for simplicity of the model. I recommend using the mapping plugin (which can do this for both mapping in and out).

Comment: see the input types change as in a1 --> Text, a2--> Checkbox and so on. I am not dynamically creating the controls on iteration of records. I need to create them as the form is present. But the record elements need to be injected if not present.

Comment: Can you please provide an example. I tried with the mapping plugin. Not able to conclude. :(